# VSTS Artifact conditions not met incorrect condition evaluation

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, release, build-definition

I may be missing something here but dont know what. As shown in the images, my build artifact is created from 'dev' branch and has 'dev' tag but VSTS is incorrectly evaluating the condition (or my expectation in wrong ).

**VSTS Build Artifact**

[image: VSTS Build Artifact]

**VSTS Release Trigger**

[image]

Comment: When is the tag being applied to the build? Before or after the release is created?

Comment: Please ignore, there was a space in the tag

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. It works fine now after removing the space.

Answer (score 0):

There was a space in name of the tag which was not apparently visible on build artifact